# How to identify a GeoJSON LineString self-intersection?

Tags: javascript, geojson, linestring

I am working on a (hobby) project where I am processing gps data (GeoJSON LineStrings) in which this often occurs. I am looking for a solution using JavaScript because I would like to do this client-side.

I am already using [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html) and [turfjs](http://turfjs.org/) but to my knowledge they both are missing this feature.

note: I opened an issue (as feature request to extend *turf.[kinks](http://turfjs.org/docs/#kinks)* so it covers LineString as well) with the hope turf will cover this gap one day -> https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*turf.[kinks](http://turfjs.org/docs/#kinks)* now covers LineString as well and returns the coordinates of self-intersections.

*note: the issue I opened (https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/528) has been fixed by the turfjs team.*

Answer (score 3):

You could try the JSTS topology suite.  [Here](https://engblog.nextdoor.com/fast-polygon-self-intersection-detection-in-javascript-a405ba40dd50#.je5enrlbb) is a description of the process for polygons you could adapt to your needs.

[geojson-utils](https://github.com/maxogden/geojson-js-utils) does not have a self-intersection check per se but, by iterating over the segments of a line you cold use its line-intersection function to test for self intersection.  This approach is a bit bit more 'roll-your-own' but would work.

Comment: thanks. I also searched a lot and stumbled over the article describing JSTS. still a bit reluctant to use because it also looks a bit "roll-your-own" :)